# get the original branch of ref branch

Tags: git, gitlab, teamcity

I'm trying to watch for changes on branches that have merge requests on them and then checkout them.

Scenario:

1. developer creates  branchX
2. developer creates merge request MergeRequest1 in gitlab for branchX
3. developer pushes to branchX
4. team city watched +:refs/(merge-requests/*)/head and detects a change

**Actual:**
team city checks out refs/merge-requests/1/head to local merge-requests/1

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
team city checks out refs/merge-requests/1/head to local branchX

How do I get `branchX`?