# What is a original/refs/remotes/... branch in git

Tags: git, git-refspec

I am using git for my project. During that I get some strange branches. If I use *gitk* to analyze, I can see that the name of these branches is something like `original/refs/remotes/origin/<branch-name>` There is also a local version of this branch. (`original/refs/head/<branch-name>`) The problem is, that these branches duplicates some of my commits. The history looks very strange. I am also not able to delete those. If I list my branches with 'git branch --list --all', they are not shown. So maybe they aren't real branches.

These constructs are not in my remote repository. If I clone the remote repository, they are gone.

What are these branch like things ? Why do they exist and how to delete them ?

Here is a little screenshot:

[image]

#### Edit:

After some more researche I found the following [SE qeustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654822/remove-refs-original-heads-master-from-git-repo-after-filter-branch-tree-filte). Because of that I will mark this question as duplicate. Thank you all for your support.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec

Comment: To improve your chance of getting an answer, can you let us know what research you've done and what did you find? Even if you haven't found a useful answer on Stackoverflow, include links to questions that haven't helped, as this can show  how your question is different from other poblems... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @mike Of course you are right. Some links were very helpfull. But unfortunately I found nothing. The only site I found is this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962509/get-the-original-branch-of-ref-branch). But I am quite sure that the only accordance between this question and my qeustion ist the word "original". Of course I will keep searching on this. I will give further informations as soon as I know something.